# Removing motion sensor from floodlight

Tags: wiring

I removed the motion sensor from my floodlights since it no longer works. It has 4 neutral wires bundled together.(2 for the lights, 1 for attaching to the house wire and 1 for the sensor) I cut the wire for the sensor.  Do I have to remove the cut wire from the nut? or can I leave it as is and put tape over it? or do I have to put a nut on the cut wire?
If I just use tape, will electricity melt the tape?
(I tried to attach picture, but server is not working)

Comment: Just as easy to remove it than it is to put a nut or tape over it.  Looks nicer also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electricity won't melt the tape because the tape, properly installed, is preventing the electricity from flowing. The problem is that tape by itself can sometimes come off and a wire nut on a single wire is generally less secure than a wire nut on multiple wires, because they are designed that way.

There are definitely times/places where taping and/or wire nut over a single wire is the thing to do:

- Temporary setups - e.g., until a fixture or appliance is replaced
- Extra wires coming out of a cable for future use - e.g., /3 used for a future 120V/240V circuit but currently only needs 120V (hot/neutral) or 240V (hot/hot).

However, when you have a short wire (pigtail) which is no longer needed and the other end is easily removable (wire nut or Wago), removing it is by far the best policy. New pigtails can be added later if needed, and this makes the box just a little bit cleaner. There are enough overloaded boxes out there, so removing wires when you can is a good thing.